# Why must a callback be provided to fs.appendFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`fs.appendFile` takes a callback function as the third argument. This argument cannot be null. But why? If I am just throwing some text to a log file, I do not care about waiting for that to be completed, and there is no "callback" for my use case.

Just wondering why it was not implemented as optional.

Comment: Then just pass a function and have it do nothing. The mistake of not recognising that the method is asynchronous is much more likely.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting here. It's a perfectly reasonable question, and it's asked clearly and completely.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I thought it was a reasonable question. IMO most callbacks should be optional, and providing a no-op function as the callback just looks sloppy.

Answer (score 6):

Because errors can happen, and the only way those can be reported to your code is by calling your callback, and your code is expected (e.g., by the Node.js API) to handle the possibility that errors happen.

You can ignore errors if you want to by passing in a no-op function, but by requiring the callback, the API discourages just ignoring the possibility errors occur.

In general, Node.js's pre-Promises API works consistently: functions that complete their work asynchronously accept a callback, and call that callback with either an error as the first argument (if something went wrong) or `null` as the first argument (if the work was successful). `fs.appendFile` is just an example of that.

Comment: I understand all of that, but still disagree that it should be required. I can still write bad code by providing a bad callback -- the API can't stop me from that!

Comment: @JoshM. - Quite true and sadly it's all too common. :-) I agree with their decision, but I understand why you don't.